# Changing env values across bash sessions in a remote server

Tags: bash, ssh, server

Hi there what I like to do is:
using ENV values from the server A and B I would like to set them on the server C. Also ENVs on server C should be set in that way that it would be permanent, ie. staying there across next bash sessions. And the circle begins: again on server A values are changed and they should be updated on server C (available across sessions).

So on server A I have set:
VAR1=test_value
(echoing this gives me proper values)

Then I'm using bash script on server A which connects to server C and should set ENVs there permanently.

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" \
  "user@${SERVER_IP}" \
  VAR1="${VAR1}" \
  "bash -s" <<'ENDSSH'>&1
    source .envtrg // I'm sourcing this to retrieve values set by B
    export VAR1=$VAR1
    envsubst '${VAR1}' < .envsrc > .envtrg
    source .envtrg

ENDSSH
```

And envsrc file looks like this:

```
export VAR1=${VAR1} //set by server A
export VAR2=${VAR2} //set by server B
```

The idea here is that server A should set its values being able to read values from server B (on server C), and the oposite server B should set its values being able to read values from server A (on the server C). How can I get this working. `envsubst` keeps old values for some reason (once set)

Comment: Sounds like you should use some sort of configuration management utility. Trivially, check the file into `git` and have the servers `git pull` periodically. For more scalable solutions, probably look at `cfengine` or `ansible` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could create a shell script, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#INSTALL@ /usr/local/bin/setvareverywhere
distr=$1
shift
var="$1"
shift
val="$*"
i_am=$(hostname)
for host in a b c ; do
    if [ "$i_am" = "$host" ] ; then
        tmp=$(mktemp)
        grep -v "^$var=" ~/.envtrg >$tmp
        echo "$var='$val'" >> $tmp
        mv $tmp ~/.envtrg
    else
        if [ "$distr" = "yes" ; then
            ssh $host usr/local/bin/setvareverywhere no "$var" "$val"
        fi
    fi
done
```